# How to temporarily highlight editable columns of Ext JS grid panel (version 4.2.1)

Tags: extjs

I am using a grid panel from ExtJS 4.2.1. I have some column definitions with editor : 'textfield' (editable columns) and some without editor (read-only columns).

What I want?

I want to temporarily highlight the editable column with a background color at the on mouse over event to that specific column.

I request for help. Please guide. I have spent lot of time on it and all in vain :(

Regards,
Jagpreet Singh

TASK - When mouse is placed over columns Editable 1 and 2 below (having editor config option), I want the target column to be highlight temporarily with some bright color for few seconds.

```
Ext.define('XX.view.account.Portfolios', {
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
plugins : {
    ptype : 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit : 1
},
columns : [{
    text : 'Read Only 1',
    flex : 1,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'ro1'
}, {
    text : 'Read Only 2',
    flex : 2,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'ro2'
}, {
    text : 'MV',
    flex : 1,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'mv'
}, {
    text : 'Editable 1',
    flex : 1,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'e1',
    editor : 'textfield'
}, {
    text : 'Editable 2',
    flex : 1,
    sortable : true,
    dataIndex : 'e2',
    editor : 'textfield'
}
```

Comment: Trap mouseover event and use .getEl().highlight() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lorenz suggested you can catch the **itemmouseenter** event and then highlight the editable rows calling **highlight** method, in order to only highlight those cells that have editors associated you probably can use a class applied to those columns, and then select the matching elements on the mouse enter event handler, something like this:

```
itemmouseenter: function (grid, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
        var node = grid.getNode(record);
        var cells = Ext.dom.Query.select('.editable-cell', node);

        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            Ext.fly(cells[i]).highlight();
        }
    }
```

You can see a [**working sample here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VszkV/). 
Hope it helps to solve your problem

Comment: I am short of words to thank You. Big help. Thank you so much. Works great :)

Comment: Not working on IE :( I use IE9. Please guide. I also tried the option of animation css mentioned below. None worked.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? If not can you supply a sample code so I can give a try? Sorry for the delayed response I was away from the computer the whole weekend

Comment: This solution works for Firefox but not IE (9). I also tried the other option mentioned below - CSS animation but that also didn't worked on IE (9). Simply open the Working sample provided above on IE (9). Thanks for your helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

another option here with CSS animation: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16a

Comment: The problem probably will be **IE <= 9** versions which doesn't support CSS animations. IE is such a PITA :(